# Date format '/' not working in some of devices in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I have using datetime property and this property is converted to string format as "dd/MM/yyyy".
This string format is working in some of devices only. i have ran my application in redmi note 5 pro device. In this device, it does not working in given format. I have used below code,

Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}

I got output as 02.01.2020
so, please let me know, if you know about this issue and please give me any suugesstions on this.

Comment: That's because the backslash is the date separator and the actual character used is based on the current culture.  You can force it to be backslashes by delimiting them like this `dd'/'MM'/'yyy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator